# fit pc web view to phone web view html

Tags: javascript, html, css, webview

My HTML file creates an iframe for each YouTube video specified in the URL's query parameters and inserts the iframes into a div element with the ID videos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Video Embedder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="videos"></div>
    <script>
      // Get embedded video URLs from the current URL's query parameters
      const currentUrl = window.location.href;
      const index = currentUrl.indexOf("?");
      if (index === -1) {
        // No query parameters found in the current URL
        document.getElementById("videos").innerHTML = "<p>No videos found</p>";
      } else {
        const newUrl = currentUrl.slice(index + 7)
        const videoList = newUrl.split(";")
        for (let i = 0; i < videoList.length; i++) {
          videoList[i] = videoList[i].replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
        }
        // Create a document fragment
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (let i = 0; i < videoList.length; i++) {
          let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
          iframe.src = videoList[i] + "?controls=1";
          iframe.frameborder = "0";
          iframe.allow = "accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture";
          iframe.allowfullscreen = "";
          // Add the iframe to the document fragment
          fragment.appendChild(iframe);
        }
        // Insert the document fragment into the div
        document.getElementById("videos").appendChild(fragment);
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #eee;
      }

      #videos {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      iframe {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 281px;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like that the video view fit the same in my phone web browser.

I mean by that dezoom or adjust height and width keeping the 500px and 281px ratio.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65bHx.jpg)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpTMx.jpg)

Comment: You set a fixed width to your iframe...

Comment: I have added picture, it it mainly a zoom problem

Comment: try to set a responsive width to your iframe